# How do you kill a python subprocess if it generates too much output on stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program that either terminates with almost no output, or it prints stuff to standard out for 10 minutes before terminating.  Currently I run the process using subprocess.Popen with stdout, where the output is coming from, going to /dev/null (I am on OSX).

I don't want to wait 10 minutes for the program to kill itself, I would rather notice that it has produced more than say 1000 lines of output, and then kill the program, otherwise let it go.

Any advice as to how one might accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the stdout of the subprocess until it outputs XXXX (limit) bytes and then `kill` it?

Comment: Since you're already using `subprocess.Popen`, don't send stdout to /dev/null -- just read lines from it, and when you've read more than 1000 then kill the process. Seems straightforward.